# "Recent activity" vote counts are missing/corrupt

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

My Recent Activity page on meta has started cutting off reputation values (it's still there after a reload).  A "20" has been cut off to a "2", and a "10" is missing entirely.

The problem is definitely in the source, not the rendering; here's the HTML snippet:

```
<tr>
<td style="width:70px">
<div class="date" title="2009-11-13 23:33:58Z">29m</div></td>
<td style="width:50px">
<div class="upvote">1</div></td>
<td>
<a href="/questions/29518/can-and-should-stack-overflow-automatically-rewrite-bit-ly-links/29520#29520" class="answer-hyperlink">Can and should Stack Overflow automatically rewrite bit.ly links?</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px">
<div class="date" title="2009-11-13 23:12:58Z">50m</div></td>
<td style="width:50px">
<div class="upvote">1<br><b>2</b></div></td>

<td>
<a href="/questions/29615/what-is-our-reward-for-voting-what-is-the-metric-for-voting/29696#29696" class="answer-hyperlink">What is our reward for voting? What is the metric for voting?</a></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design. You've hit the rep cap.

The **2** is what you were only able to score before hitting 200 for the UTC day.

The blank is because you've now hit that cap but still getting upvoted.

Accepted answers and bounties are not beholden to the rep cap, so you can still see an increase in your magic numbers.

Comment: oooooh! I may have hit the rep cap before but probably never saw what it looked like on the recent activity screen. thanks all :)

Comment: PS. I wonder if there is anything that could/should be done to make this more obvious? or should we presume that anyone who has hit the cap ought to be able to figure it out for themselves?

Comment: @Ether - if you're hitting the rep cap you should be able to work it out for yourself. Especially if you hit the "today" tab