# Got an upvote, but no reputation (no community wiki)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [No reputation for upvote given?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/no-reputation-for-upvote-given)
>   [“Recent activity” vote counts are missing/corrupt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/recent-activity-vote-counts-are-missing-corrupt)

I clicked the envelope next to my username to check what was going on, and saw this:

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/5215/norep.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/5215/norep.png)

Yet, [the question this was an answer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203663/return-a-reference-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-php) nor [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203663/return-a-reference-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-php/2203693#2203693) are marked community wiki.

Comment: You hit your rep cap for the day. Click on the envelope and then the "today" tab. Your reputation should be a big blue 200.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28402/no-reputation-for-upvote-given

Comment: don't feel bad, I was confused when this happened to me too: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29716/recent-activity-vote-counts-are-missing-corrupt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that's because [you hit the rep cap for the day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow). Click the envelope next to your name and click on 'Today'. How much reputation have you gained?

Comment: You're right, it reports 202 as the reputation gained. I totally didn't think of the reputation cap.